# WPF Transparent background

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

Please note that I´m slowly shifting from WinForms to WPF so this might be trivial :/

I´m trying to have 2 radio buttons partly overlapping, the problem is that even tho I have Background="Transparent" I still can see the background hiding part of my second radio button.

[image: figure 1]

And here is my wpf code [image]

Thank you for your time :)

Pajamac out.

Comment: I don't see any transparency on your `RadioButton`.  Please show more of your XAML, as *text*, not as a screenshot.

Comment: You need to play with Opacity values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the styles on the `RadioButton` to transparent. Place this code in your `App.xaml` of your `WPF` app, it will change any `RadioButton` to transparent.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```